# Generate random list of names based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have gotten a random list to generate from a master list and exclude 2 items from that list (`thing 1` & `thing 2`), however even after I run the macro several times it will still populate those excluded items occasionally.

When I step into it the macro seems to run fine. One note the excluded items populate less frequently when I select them to not be excluded.

```
Sub populate()

Dim usedList As Object
Set usedList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    usedList.Add "thing 1", 1
    usedList.Add "thing 10", 2


Dim SrcRange As Range, FillRange As Range
Dim c As Range, r As Long

Dim i As Integer
i = 12
Set SrcRange  = Sheets("Staffing").Range("B2:B21")
Set FillRange  = Sheets("Staffing").Range("F2:F" & i)

r = SrcRange.Cells.Count
For Each c In FillRange
Do
c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FillRange, c.Value) < 2

If usedList.Exists(c.Value) Then
    c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of `s` and `f` if you just move right ahead to `Set SrcRange = s` and `Set FillRange = f`?

Comment: sorry I copied it from another part of the module. It should be cleaned up

Comment: So, you're replacing values you want to exclude with a value from a random row? If so, that won't replace all values you want to exclude, because some percent of the time it'll just pick itself as the 'value' to replace it with, or some other row with a disallowed value

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just added a Do Loop to see if the random list value already existed and if it did to re-run the Rnd function until it found an item that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this seems to work. I added a Do Loop to double check the value against the list. Ive run it a few times already and it seems to fix it. Please validate! Hopefully this helps someone.

```
    For Each c In FillRange
    Do
        c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
        If usedList.Exists(c.Value) Then
            Do While usedList.Exists(c.Value)
                c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
            Loop

        End If
    Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FillRange, c.Value) < 2

Next c
```